# Do bar-ends with brake levers exist?

Tags: handlebars

I'd like to have those upward bar-ends, but with brake levers attached.

It's pretty hard to explain without a picture, but I hope someone understands what I'm looking for.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Are you talking about bull-horn bars? If so, you can get TT brakes...other types will work, but these will fit right into the bar ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out, you're asking about mounting TT levers on bullhorn bars, [like so](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tt+brake+levers+bullhorn).

It's pretty popular (I keep meaning to replace the crosstop levers on my own bullhorns with these).

It's worth checking whether a set of levers are for internally- or externally-routed cables: bullhorns aren't likely to be fitted for internal cable routing, so unless you're happy drilling them yourself, external cables are a better bet.

Answer (score 7):

With any number of brake puller solutions such as this: [http://www.amazon.com/Problem-Solvers-Cable-Doubler-Levers/dp/B001CK0R64](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CK0R64) you can have as many levers as you want. Installing an additional lever and cabling isn't hard but if you don't want to do it your LBS will have no problem.

Comment: It seems 'reverse brake levers' or 'bar-end brake levers' is the thing I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @ExplodingRat: Or "inverse brake levers"

Comment: Yeah. Now I only need to figure out how to attach them to some bar-ends.

Comment: The first step is shooing the barflies out of the way.

Comment: Depending on the bar ends you may be able to remove an end cap and use TT style brake levers which sit inside the bar ends. Failing that there are any number of bmx/mtb/etc style brake levers which have a clamp which could secure to your bar ends either lever end up or down based on how you clean up the cables.